# checkbox has to be clicked twice to execute the animation

Tags: javascript, animation, checkbox, onclick

I created a custom animated checkbox that looks like a switch. I used class names for modifying the animations of my checkbox. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<label>
    <input class="cb" type="checkbox">
    <div class="ball"></div> <!-- don't mind this -->
</label>
```

Javascript

```
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

$('label').onclick = function() {
    if(!$('.cb').checked) {
        this.classList.add('clicked');
    } else {
        this.classList.remove('clicked');
    }
}
```

It worked successfully, but not perfectly, because at INITIAL click of the checkbox (which means after the page load), you have to click it twice in order for the first animation to be executed. I tried `event.stopPropagation()` but it's still the same. I also tried `event.preventDefault()` but it only worked on first animation.

Comment: Hi, Please try changing that if condition to $('.cb').checked by removing '!'.

Comment: [element].checked will be true immediately after checking the input.

Comment: @RohithKP `$(this)` will refer to the document.

Comment: @SLePort Sorry..I changed that part in the above comment.

Comment: @SLePort [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rohith_KP/jn5L4052/)

Comment: @RohithKP Thanks. I didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

I would listen to the change event rather than the click event of the label—you could be facing a race condition.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<label>
  <input id="toggles-animation" type="checkbox">

  <span class="animate">
    Select me
  </span>
</label>
```

The checkbox has an id of `toggles-animation` and this is the element we listen to for the change.

The element inside it has the `animate` class on it—it will be the one animating. This element is the one we need to add the `clicked` class to, so that it has **both** `clicked` and `animate`.

We can do this by adding an `onchange` listener to the checkbox input:

```
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
var el = $('#toggles-animation');

el.onchange = function (evt) {
  var animateElement = this.nextSibling.nextSibling;
  var toggle = this.checked ? 'add' : 'remove';

  animateElement.classList[toggle]('clicked');
};
```

You can query the `animateElement` any way you like—I just used the sibling element. The important thing is that there is a class that has the animation and that class is not removed or added, but rather a supplementary class is.

So, when checked: `<span class="animate clicked">`

I've created a demo where the background starts turquoise and animates to pink. You can see the working demo on Codepen: http://codepen.io/tinacious/pen/WoMoZo